# For loop to count the number of vowels in a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm writing a function that will count the number of vowels in a string.
I decided to use a for-loop and an if-statement to do this.

```
function vowels (string) {
    var counter = 0;
    for (let i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (i == 'a' || i == 'e' || i == 'i' || i == 'o' || i == 'u') {
            counter++;
        }return counter;
    } 
}
```

This is my code. When I call the function, it only returns 0 no matter how many vowels my string has. What's wrong?

Comment: 'i' is the number variable.  you are being compared to number variable with characters.

Comment: The return exits the loop and the function. Consider putting the return outside of the loop? Also, `i == 'a'` doesn't make sense since `i` is a number, not a string

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

1. You're not looping through the string but the length of it. You need to use the length to get the position of the string.
2. You're returning the counter, exiting the function, on index 0.

I also added a `toLowerCase` to account for casing. `A === a` but that depends on your use case.

Always use === operator when validating types. You can learn more [here](https://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm) but basically == compares value only and === compares value and type.

e.g. `0 == '0' equals true` and `0 === '0' equals false`

```
function vowels (value) {
    let counter = 0;
    let char = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        char = value[i].toLowerCase();
        if (char === 'a' || char === 'e' || char === 'i' || char === 'o' || char === 'u') {
            counter++
        }
        
    } 
    return counter;
}

vowels("AaBbCcDdEe");
```

returns 4. AaEe.

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues:

1. You need to finish your iteration through the string letters before returning the total count. Currently, the `return counter;` is inside the for-loop.
2. You also need to compare a letter `string[i]` with a vowel during each iteration. `i` will compare a number to a vowel not a letter.

   ```
    function vowels(string) {
        var counter = 0;
        for (let i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
            if (string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u') {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
   ```